# PHP: how to get a day in last week?

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to get last week's, say, Monday? If today is Tuesday, I do not want yesterday's Monday. Rather, I want the Monday 8 days ago (last week's Monday). Then I want that Monday's proceeding Sunday. Basically, I'm trying to get the date range for last week, Monday to Sunday.

This doesn't always work right:

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Monday')`

Suggestions?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to ignore the current week, and get a weekday of the last full week?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `strtotime('last week Monday')` also doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: well, week usually got 7 days, so you can try do do some math yourself on time stamp based on that assumption...

Comment: ... Current day num + 7 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use “this week” format:

```
$monday = strtotime( 'this week', strtotime( '7 days ago' ) );
$sunday = strtotime( '+ 6 days', $monday  );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/sEtJv)**</kbd>

“this_week” returns monday of previous week, then — adding 6 days — you obtain the monday of relative week.

Comment: This will work regardless of what day it is executed?

Comment: if you want previous week of custom date (eg 2015-03-01), replace `strtotime( '7 days ago' )` with `strtotime( '7 days ago', strtotime('2015-03-01') )`

Answer (score 1):

The `strtotime` function accepts the current date as a parameter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Just pass in `strtotime('last Sunday')` as the parameter to get a weekday of the last full week.

```
$beginning_of_week = strtotime('last Sunday');
$result = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Monday', $beginning_of_week));

echo $result;
```

Comment: The problem with this by itself is if you run it on a Sunday, it will use the previous Sunday thus returning 2 mondays ago

Comment: That's what I would need, though.

Comment: If today is Sunday, I do not want the date of the most recent Monday. I want the date of the Monday before the most recent Monday -- then the proceeding Sunday.

Comment: Ok, so you want to reference 13 days ago on a Sunday as last Monday?  This is where our definitions will differ I guess.